# Updating status bar with opened file name

Tags: python, tkinter, executable, statusbar, g-code

With amazing help of other stackoverflow users I have made this code for reading out some data out of a gcode file and doing some calculations on it. It is almost done and the last 2 things I have problem with are:

1) I would like the status bar update to display message "File [name of the uploaded file] is uploaded" after the gcode file will be uploaded with the button.

2) I would like to make executable for the program so it can be standalone and work on Mac OS and Windows. I have downloaded and installed (I am on mac) pyinstaller and I am performing some actions on my .py file, the end result looks like ready applications but they don't work.

Thank you in advance for help and all the inputs, I am a complete newbie in python but I have already learned so much from you.

This is the sample gcode file for tests: [sample GCODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jadu94v9fji4fhb/holder.gcode?dl=0)

And this is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)
class Window(Frame):

    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        Frame.__init__(self, master)   

        #reference to the master widget, which is the tk window                 
        self.master = master

        #with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        self.init_window()

    # Load the gcode file in and extract the filament value
    def get_filament_value(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f_gcode:
            data = f_gcode.read()
            re_value = re.search('filament used = .*? \(([0-9.]+)', data)

            if re_value:
                return float(re_value.group(1))

            else:
                return 0.0


    def read_gcode(self):
        root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GCODE files", "*.gcode"), ("All files", "*.*")))

        volume = self.get_filament_value(root.fileName)
        mass = volume * 1.13
        price = mass * 0.175

        self.volume_text.set('Volume is {:.2f} cm3'.format(volume))
        self.mass_text.set('Mass is {:.2f} g'.format(mass))
        self.price_text.set('Price is {:.2f} DKK'.format(price))

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def about_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About", "This software is created by Bartosz Domagalski and helps to find used filament parameters from Sli3er generated GCODE")

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("Filament Data")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a menu instance
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # create the file object)
        file = Menu(menu)
        help = Menu(menu)

        # adds a command to the menu option, calling it exit, and the
        # command it runs on event is client_exit
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        help.add_command(label="About", command=self.about_popup)

        #added "file" to our menu
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)


        #Creating the labels
        l_instruction = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=TOP, text="Load GCODE file to find volume, \n weight and price of used filament.")
        l_instruction.pack()


        #Creating the button
        gcodeButton = Button(self, text="Load GCODE", command=self.read_gcode)
        gcodeButton.pack()
#        gcodeButton.place(x=60, y=50)

        #Label of the used filament

        l1 = Label(self, text="")
        l1.pack()
        l2 = Label(self, text="")
        l2.pack()
        l3 = Label(self, text="")
        l3.pack()

        self.volume_text = StringVar()
        l = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.volume_text)
        l.pack()

        l4 = Label(self, text="")
        l4.pack()

        self.mass_text = StringVar()
        m = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.mass_text)
        m.pack()

        l5 = Label(self, text="")
        l5.pack()

        self.price_text = StringVar()
        p = Label(self, justify=CENTER, compound=BOTTOM, textvariable=self.price_text)
        p.pack()


        #status Bar
        status = Label(self, text="Waiting for file... ", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False,height=False);
root.geometry("220x300")


#creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

#mainloop 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What _specific_ part about updating a status bar are you struggling with?

Comment: I have read a lot about status bars and python in general on different forums and tutorials. This is my first code ever and as I also have been told previously probably I started with too complicated problem. But that was the only real life problem where I would need programming and I chose python as it seems the most usable for many things also there is a lot of information on the internet. The specific problem is that I can't figure out how to to correlate the button press to switch the status from one to another. I am quite new to stackoverflow but I noticed people are quite guarded in the

Comment: begining but maybe I wrongly assumed that this is the place of help of such a beginners as myself. I will take 2 weeks to figure one thing and maybe for someone here it would be just 30 seconds to write couple lines of code. I am also learning this way as I find interaction with another human way more rewarding that reading a lot. And there is really a lot when you learn new programming language (without having any particular experience in coding or programming in general). No hard feelings just wanted to point it out :)

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't so much a place for beginners to get help as it is a place to get specific answers to specific questions. This isn't a tutoring service or a code writing service. We expect you to do most of the work. You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have read this prior to posting and I don't think that I have done anything really wrong. You might be right though about not being a place for beginners but I haven't seen that information anywhere. And still I don't get it why somebody if feels like helping can't answer my question it is not a must. I think my question is quite specific and the answer could be such as well. I understand your concerns about keeping the place clean, I really do but still I don't think that hoping for help of those much more experienced is something wrong.